# Cognito in Java, sign up user with Force Change Password status

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I'm totally new to AWS and specifically Cognito. I tried watching tutorials, reading documentations, but I can't really say I'm aware of what's going on.

Right now, I'm using IntelliJ and downloaded the following library:
*Maven:software.amazon.awssdk.cognitoidentityprovider:2.17.291.*

What I want to do is:

- Using a GUI I created in JavaFX, that should be used only by administrators, I want an admin to insert an email and username.
- The password must be temporary, preferably automatically generated.
- Upon first login, that user uses the temporary password but needs to change it. From what I've read, this regards the UserStatus **"FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD"**.

I don't really know where to start. There's not a tutorial that explains this with accuracy. I'm getting lost reading about all the classes I could use, without understanding a good pattern I should follow. Can you give me some help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"There's not a tutorial that explains this with accuracy".

If you are looking in the AWS Service Guide, you will not find this answer. However, if you want to learn HOW TO perform Cognito use cases using the AWS SDK for Java v2, then look in the ***[AWS Code Library](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/what-is-code-library.html)***. Here you will find very detailed Cognito code examples that uses the AWS SDK for Java v2 (as well as other AWS SDK examples).

Here is a Java v2 code example that you should look at that covers the functionality you specified (plus more).

This code example shows how to:

1. Sign up a user with a user name, password, and email address.
2. Confirm the user from a code sent in email.
3. Set up multi-factor authentication by associating an MFA application with the user.
4. Sign in by using a password and an MFA code.

[Sign up a user with an Amazon Cognito user pool that requires MFA using an AWS SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/cognito-identity-provider_example_cognito-identity-provider_Scenario_SignUpUserWithMfa_section.html)

Comment: The AWS Code Lib is a fairly new doc. All the latest code examples are in the doc.